# JavaFX Scene object - why is called a "container" if it's not part of a scene graph

Tags: javafx

Just learning javafx.

I admit there is something fundamental I don't understand about the nomenclature here. Javafx docs call the Scene object "container for all content in a scene graph", yet, obviously, this has nothing to do with being the root of the "scene graph" (not to mention nothing to do with a Swing Container). What is the role of Scene? Where can I read up on this, except for Oracle docs?

Comment: The `Scene` contains the root of the scene graph... which in turn contains all the (other) nodes in the scene graph. So in that sense the `Scene` is a container for all content in the scene graph.

Comment: Oh. I was under the impression that is doesn't simply contain the root, as you can't just add(Node) to a Scene (i.e. using the same pattern as with all the other elements of this hierarchy)... and the Scene class doc isn't clear again.

Comment: `add` would imply that it could contain multiple root nodes, which would make no sense. How is the [`Scene` doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) unclear: "The application must specify the root Node for the scene graph by setting the root property."?

Comment: Never mind, I understand now. Thanks. It was unclear, because for instance: most diagrams omit the Scene object in the hierarchy, or because if something is called root that suggests it's a topmost object.